# Ваш проект ссылается на последнюю версию Entity Framework. Однако

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных

проблема следующая: 
[image: В чем ошибка]

Возникает эта проблема на этапе добавления модели EDM. Сразу после формирования connectionString

Подготовительные работы (референсы, плагины, все дела) вел по инструкции из ответа к этому посту: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031269/enable-entity-framework-6-for-mysql-c-in-winforms-of-microsoft-visual-studio
Выдало эту ошибку. Тогда я полным инсталлятором MySQL обновил все связанное с MySQL (в том числе и коннектор, и плагин) до новых версий. Потом снес весь App.Config, Packages.config, все Референсы и добавил референсы по-новой в этом же порядке еще раз (упомянутые файлы перезаписались).

После всех этих махинаций, ошибка осталась. Единственное, чего я не делал, так это не выполнял пункт 9, так как в папке ProgramFile MySQL нет папки MySQL Connector Net 6.8.3 (хотя в ProgramFile (x86) была.

---

### App.config

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <!--<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>-->
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.9.8.0" newVersion="6.9.8.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

---

### packages.config

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MySql.Data" version="6.9.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MySql.Data.Entities" version="6.8.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MySql.Web" version="6.9.8" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 1):

В общем, я разобрался. Решение мое состоит, по сути, из трех проектов отдельных: три библиотеки классов (в одну подключается БДя и прописана вся работа с ней, друга общая, третья - интерфейс).

Так вот все референсы, весь аппКонфиг нужно было дублировать и в третью библиотеку тоже, поскольку она является запускаемой (раньше я их все пихал только в библиотеку для работы с БД)

Comment: Я вам больше скажу, `app.config` имеет смысл *только* для запускаемых проектов.

Comment: Ого, буду знать. Вроде как тогда проблема решилась, я немного поработал с БД, потом решил её поменять. После изменений, попытался обновить модель и потерпел неудачу (мастер моделей просто закрывался по нажатию на "Далее" после этапа формирования connectionString). Я начал производить те же действия, что и раньше, но не помогло. Тогда я полез в пакеты проекта и увидел, что там у меня наустановлено куча хлама. Я все снес (и референсы с апп конфигом и пекеджем тоже), но при запуске проекта, NuGet восстановил EntityFramework 6.1.3. Почему так происходит, не подскажете? Может, референс не вижу?

Comment: NuGet умеет автоматически восстанавливать пакеты из файла `packages.config`. А вы их откуда удаляли?

Comment: Но при этом даже после добавления всех библиотек, указанных в посте, ссылку на который я дал в вопросе, мастер моделей пишет, что ему не удалось найти поставщик БД. Предлагает выбрать 5.0. а в NuGet пишет, что EntityFrameworks уже установлен (версия 6.1.3.). Хотя в референсах не вижу его

Comment: Удалял и из app.config, и из packages.config, в этом и странность

Comment: Очистил полностью эти два файла и снес references. Операцию проделал и в исполняемой библиотеке классов, и в той, которая рассчитана на работу с БД

Comment: А, и из папки пакетов в папке проекта тоже удалял

Comment: Полез еще в папку obj/debug библиотеки, в которую добавлял модель, а там есть файлы от нее. Может, это влияет на добавление EntityFrameworks в проект?

Comment: Снес эти две папки. Снес опять Ентити отовсюду. На этот раз при открытии проекта, ничего автоматически не добавилось. Попытался добавить EntityFramework самостоятельно через NuGet. Референс добавился 6.0.0.0. В App.Config 6.0.0.0, в package.config прописана версия 6.1.3, в папке пакетов в проекте 6.1.3. Пока лазил по версиям, выбило студию. Перезапустилась, В референсах уже нет Entities, а в пакетах прописан и в папке пакетов в проекте тоже есть 6.1.3 и там, и там